# Yii accessRules expression not working

Tags: php, yii, rbac

In my controller, I have

```
    /**
 * @return array action filters
 */
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
}

/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow players to comment on games
            'actions'=>array('createComment'),
            'roles'=>array('createComment'),
        ),
  array('allow', // allow users to update and delete their own comments
    'actions'=>array('deleteComment'),
    'expression'=>'return $user->id==Game::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery("id"))->author->id;',
  ),
        array('allow', // allow admin users to create, update, delete and manage games
            'actions'=>array('admin','create','update','delete','deleteComment'),
    'roles'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

But for some reason, the expression on deleteComment always gives me a 403 error (not authorised). Even though I have tested that expression and get true. Even putting 'expression'=>'return true;' doesn't work. :( I'm completely confused... Any ideas?
Thanks, Brad(:

Answer (score 10):

You have an extra `return` in the beginning of your expression. Yii [already adds one](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/base/CComponent.php#602), so having two results in a syntax error. Remove yours and you 'll be good to go.